# html in dev console differs from source html

Tags: html, ajax, forms, browser, html-table

Example 1 is live at http://redspider.ddns.net/dev_config.html

Notice there's no script on the page; no elements are dynamically added.

The html source has a `<table>` containing multiple `<form>`, with `<input>` and `<tr>`, `<td>` inside `<form>`.

source html: 
`<form method=POST name="SimpleLink Configuration" action=mode_config>
<tr><td>...</td></tr></form>`.

The rendered html, as shown in dev browser(both Chrome and Firefox), has form contents outside of the form, which becomes an empty form: 
`<form method=POST name="SimpleLink Configuration" action=mode_config></form>
<tr><td>...</td></tr>`.

**This makes forms non-submittable**.

Example 2 http://output.jsbin.com/waxugebabi/1

The odd thing is, the form can be submitted in example 1, but when rendered html is copied into another page(example 2), forms cannot be submitted.

**Goal**

Example 1 page is not from a modifiable source. I want to include the html in another page, while preserving the ability to submit forms. I tried getting example 1 using ajax, and while the data returned is identical to the html source, filtered contents is that of example 2.

I tried wrapping contents of the form in the form tag, but the result is a ugly CSS mess.

I also want to avoid `<iframe>`, due to unsightly scrollbars, if possible.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You do realize that 192.168.1.122 is in private address space and is entirely inaccessible to anyone outside of your local network, right?

Comment: Validate your HTML - https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Changed private address to public address: http://redspider.ddns.net/network.html

Comment: the validator says *Element form not allowed as child of element tbody in this context.* So the source html is invalid. Yet it posts, but when loaded into another page it no longer posts. http://redspider.ddns.net/network.html Could be a case of dynamically loaded html?